# Jenkins Active Choices Reactive Parameter not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Jenkins Active Choices Reactive Parameter is not working,
here is my configuration looks

[image: Active Choice Parameter]

and
[image]

and output dont have drop down for Active choice reactive parameter.
so what can be done to have dropdown for Active choice reactive parameter?
[image: Build With Parameters dont have drop down for BBB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i missed adding the Referenced parameters in Active Choices Reactive parameter section[image: Referenced parameters]